# Setting a time out with an if else statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, timeout

I have a function that is run when you mouseover and mouseout of a div.  When you mouseout I need the function to wait a second before running.  Is there a way to set a timeout on an if else statement to make this work?

HTML:

```
<div ng-mouseover="menu()" ng-mouseout="menu()"><img src="images/headermenubutton.png" style="height: 73px; width: auto; position: absolute; left: 230px; z-index: 2000;"></div>
<div class="menu" ng-mouseover="menu()" ng-mouseout="menu()" ng-show="dropdown_menu" ng-cloak>
    <a href="about_us.html"><h2 class="lighter" style="padding-top: 10px;">ABOUT US</h2></a>
    <a href="contact_us.html"><h2 class="lighter">CONTACT US</h2></a>
    <a href="/blog"><h2 class="lighter">BLOG</h2></a>
    <a href="contact_us.html#faq"><h2 class="lighter">FAQ'S</h2></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.menu = function() {
    if($scope.dropdown_menu) {
        setTimeout(function(){ $scope.dropdown_menu = false; }, 1000);
    } else {
        $scope.dropdown_menu = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: You're doing it right now. What's the issue?

Comment: It looks like you are using angular. try [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: Forgot to load $timeout as a dependency.... My bad!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, try [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)  wrapper of angular

Solution with `$timeout` used:

```
$scope.menu = function () {
    if ($scope.dropdown_menu) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.dropdown_menu = false;
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $scope.dropdown_menu = true;
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lx41yy47/